# SFML Sprite not visible

Tags: c++, sfml

So i have the following C++ code to create and display my sprite:

```
sf::Vector2f personSize(256, 256);

sf::Texture personTexture;

if (!personTexture.loadFromFile("../sprites/person.png")) {
    cout << "Error loading sprite" << endl;
}

sf::Sprite protoPerson;

protoPerson.setScale(personSize);
protoPerson.setTexture(personTexture);
protoPerson.setPosition(100, 100);
```

However the sprite is not visible. When i create rectangles instead they're visible.

Comment: You should check the return value of `loadFromFile` to determine whether it succeeded.

Comment: @VTT Yeah i added that through an if statement, iĺl edit the post, still not visible though.

Comment: Got it fixed, i used

     sf::Sprite protoPerson(personTexture);

instead